# Transparent CWnd deletes open dialog's window handle when it expires

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using a transparent window to show an unobtrusive message in my app. It all works fine but for one thing. If I have a modal dialog open when it expires, the dialog window gets destroyed. This will of course this lead to a crash as there is no wnd handle for the dialog message loop to work with. I've checked, and it happens to several different dialogs, like the AboutDlg. I'm guessing that something goes awry because of the modal message loop. If I don't have a dialog open, the app continues along fine. I tried this in `DestroyWindow`, but that didn't help:

```
SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
```

I'm checking for an update when the app starts. If there is an update I create the window with:

```
        pFrm->SetInfoPtr(InfoWnd::InitWindow(pFrm->GetActiveView(), IDB_NEWVERSION));
```

It could live on its own if the parent where the desktop. But if over a view and when the main frame moves or resizes... So now the main frame will be `InfoWnd` aware. This could be part of the solution.

This is the code for the window.

info_window.h

```
class InfoWnd : public CWnd
{
protected:
    static InfoWnd* self_ptr;
    CWnd* parent = nullptr;
    HDC memdc = nullptr;
    static BLENDFUNCTION blend;
    int width;
    int height;
    CBitmap m_bitmap;
    InfoWnd() {};

public:
    static auto GetSelfPointer() { return &self_ptr; }
    virtual ~InfoWnd() { self_ptr = nullptr; }
    virtual void PostNcDestroy() { self_ptr = nullptr; delete this; }
    static InfoWnd** InitWindow(CWnd* parnt, UINT bitmapID);
    void MoveInfoWindow(LPCRECT lpRect);

protected:
    BOOL Create(CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL);
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
};
```

info_window.cpp

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(InfoWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

InfoWnd** InfoWnd::InitWindow(CWnd* parent, UINT bitmapID) {
    assert(!self_ptr);
    self_ptr = new InfoWnd;
    if (!self_ptr->m_bitmap.LoadBitmap(bitmapID)) {
        delete self_ptr;
        self_ptr = nullptr;
        return nullptr;
    }
    BITMAP bm;
    self_ptr->m_bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
    self_ptr->width = bm.bmWidth;
    self_ptr->height = bm.bmHeight;
    self_ptr->parent = parent;
    self_ptr->Create(parent);
    return &self_ptr;
}

BOOL InfoWnd::Create(CWnd* pParentWnd)
{
    parent = pParentWnd;
    CRect parentRect;
    pParentWnd->GetWindowRect(parentRect);

    BOOL result = CreateEx( WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        AfxRegisterWndClass(0, AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_CROSS)),
        NULL, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, width, height, pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);
    if (!result)
        return FALSE;

    std::cout << "InfoWnd: " << GetSafeHwnd() << std::endl;
    MoveWindow(parentRect.right - width, parentRect.top, parentRect.right, parentRect.top);

    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;                    // the only BlendOp defined in Windows 2000
    blend.BlendFlags = 0;                                   // nothing else is special ...
    blend.AlphaFormat = 0;                              // ...
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;    // the initial alpha value

    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    SetTimer(1, 200, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}

void InfoWnd::MoveInfoWindow(LPCRECT lpRect)
{
    MoveWindow(lpRect->right - width, lpRect->top, lpRect->right, lpRect->top);
}

void InfoWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CDC dcImage;
    if (!dcImage.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc))
        return;

    BITMAP bm;
    m_bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = dcImage.SelectObject(&m_bitmap);
    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, &dcImage, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    dcImage.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
}

void InfoWnd::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
    if (blend.SourceConstantAlpha) {
        if (blend.SourceConstantAlpha == 255) {
            SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
        if (blend.SourceConstantAlpha) {
            UpdateLayeredWindow( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);
        }
        blend.SourceConstantAlpha-= 5;
        return;
    }
    KillTimer(nIDEvent);
    //this will be replaced with a post message to the parent?
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

Comment: Well then... you also need to kill the dialog that causes the problem, so that the dialog dies before the transparent window. Some message posting with WM_CLOSE and timers maybe to get a graceful exit

Comment: Hi @Sven Nilsson The idea of the notice window is that the user can continue on with whatever they would like to do. Like tools->download new version. What I may have to do if there is no better solution, is to destroy the notice window if the user 'does stuff'. But that would be an interesting challenge in itself. But I can't be kicking them out of a dialog they have called on.

Comment: Not enough code for the full picture, but have you tried making it a `WS_CHILD` instead of `WS_POPUP`.

Comment: Hi @dxiv I can't make it a child, I have users that still run windows 7. It is the nature of a layered/transparent window. I really did want to make it a child window when I started this.

Comment: @lakeweb Then use [spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-start-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) to examine the modal dialog(s). My guess is that the transparent window ends up as the parent or owner somewhere in their ancestry, and you need to find a way to prevent that.

Comment: @dxiv, spy confirms that the dialog is getting WM_DESTROY messages from the window. But when I trace into `DestroyWindow` the handle belongs to the message window. Something about the message pump when a modal is running. Will I have to create a private message pump for the info window? It is starting to look that way. Or a hook and look for messages from the info window? This is not the sandbox I play in much.

Comment: Or maybe, just delay the destruction of the info window when a dialog is running, It is invisible anyway.

Comment: @lakeweb That could be one way. The other way would be to figure out *why* the dialog ends up being owned by the overlay.

Comment: `KillTimer(1);` unconditionally kills whatever timer has the ID 1. That may or may not be yours. We don't know. The documentation for [CWnd::SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#settimer) is unambiguously clear on how to handle timer IDs: *"An application should **always** pass the return value [of `SetTimer`] to the `KillTimer` member function to kill the timer."*

Comment: I see you use std::cout to TRACE to a console Window(?). Check, if you use FreeConsole(). This will crash the application beginning in Win10. In Win7, I cannot remember.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, thanks, I fixed that. Also made the main frame become `InfoWnd` aware. Now the info window follows the movements.

Comment: hi @Tom Tom The console is optional and it is there for the whole session or not. I don't use `FreeConsole()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is pretty easy. No hooks or hacks. The `CMyApp::OnIdle(..)` does not participate while there is a modal dialog up. So a safe place to destroy the info window. `info_window.h` is already included in this translation unit as that is where the window is created.

In the above example, delete the `DestroyWindow()` found in `InfoWnd::OnTimer(..)`

Add a member in the declaration (note, one was there but now just returns the pointer):

```
bool IsDone() const { return !blend.SourceConstantAlpha; }
static auto GetSelfPointer() { return self_ptr; }
```

Then in the apps `OnIdle`:

```
if(InfoWnd::GetSelfPointer() && InfoWnd::GetSelfPointer()->IsDone())
    InfoWnd::GetSelfPointer()->DestroyWindow();
```

The reason for a pointer to a pointer is still used by the MainFrame. It checks that the info window is valid by checking that self_ptr is not null.

```
CMainFrame::OnMoving(){
    if (*pInfoWnd){
        //Move the window
    }
}
```